# How to make the map markers open into pop-ups

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogs, amcharts

So, I'm making a personal project on tumblr where I want to make a world map with city markers. I want the markers to open a pop-up when clicked and offer info depending on which city was clicked. I found amCharts had some ready made stuff for this, but I'm a total beginner and need to be instructed on how to achieve this. I'm using [this](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/) to get the city markers easily, and I found [this tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/retrieving-information-of-a-clicked-map-object/) on how to retrieve info of clicked items. But I can't figure out how to make the info open up in a pop-up. They've got a tutorial on pop-ups but it doesn't really explain how to achieve this, there's not a clear example that I could try out to get the hang of it.

Also I can't seem to actually click on the city markers, only the countries, which is something I'd also like to be able to do.

And when I preview the map it shows the names of the countries right, but when I save the page it doesn't show the countries names when I hover over them, so I need a fix for that. EDIT: I'm pretty sure this is because Tumblr turns the polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}"; into polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "username"; in the code, is there any way to bypass this or fix it? Because I don't want every country to show a tooltip that's just my username when hovered.

Like I said, I'm a beginner and the amCharts tutorials seem to assume a certain level of understanding of javascript, which I have none of. I've tried my best to read through everything that seems like it could help, but can't seem to get the hang of it. I'm confident that what I'm trying to do is achievable and probably very easy to pull off, but I lack the know-how and need actual instructions in the vein of "put x in exactly y part of the code" or "replace x with y in this part of the code" for it to 'click' for me.

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><title>{Title}</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
<link href="http://static.tumblr.com/bfthosw/vUynczxut/intro-black-64.css" rel="stylesheet">



<!---- Travelmap #1 by Sofi (castiiel.tumblr.com). DON'T REMOVE THE CREDIT OR CLAIM THE THEME AS YOURS. DON'T USE IT AS A BASE ---> 

<script type="text/javascript">
      WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'Lato:300,400:latin', 'Montserrat:700:latin' ] }
      };
      (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
          '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })(); </script>
 
<style type="text/css">



body {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/rYsfgEL.png'); /*put the url          of your background image between '', if any */
        background-attachment: fixed;
}

#map {
    position: fixed;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-251px;
    width:810px;
    height:455px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-416px;
    background:#27222A; /*Here change the map background color*/
    padding:10px 0px 16px 10px;
    border:3px solid #bbb; /*Here change the inside border color*/
    outline:3px solid #27222A; /*Here change the outline color. Better if it match the map background*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: #aaa;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: #444;
    }





  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

#title {
    width:752px;
    position: fixed;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-376px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top:-300px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'montserrat', 'intro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:700;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    color:#ddd; /*Here change the title color*/
}

#links {
    width:752px;
    position: fixed;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-376px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top:260px;
    text-align:center;
}

#links a {
    font-family:trebuchet ms, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding:5px 8px;
    display: inline;
    font-size:10px;
    letter-spacing:1.3px;
    margin:0px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#eee; /*Here change the links text color*/
    font-weight:bolder;
    background:#27222A; /*Here change the links background color*/
    border:2px solid #aaa; /*Here change the links inside border color*/
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    
}
 
</style></head>
<body>

<div id="title">MAP</div>

<div id="map">
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.map-marker {
    /* adjusting for the marker dimensions
    so that it is centered on coordinates */
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.map-marker.map-clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.pulse {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #f7f14c;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #716f42;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.map-marker .dot {
    border: 10px solid #fff601;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
    animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
   0% {
      -moz-transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 0.0;
   }
   25% {
      -moz-transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 0.1;
   }
   50% {
      -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
      opacity: 0.3;
   }
   75% {
      -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
      opacity: 0.5;
   }
   100% {
      -moz-transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 0.0;
   }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes "pulse" {
   0% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 0.0;
   }
   25% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 0.1;
   }
   50% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
      opacity: 0.3;
   }
   75% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
      opacity: 0.5;
   }
   100% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 0.0;
   }
}
</style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/dataviz.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_dataviz);
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create map instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);



// Set map definition
chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;

// Set projection
chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

// Create map polygon series
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());

// Exclude Antartica
polygonSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];

// Make map load polygon (like country names) data from GeoJSON
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;

// Add some custom data
polygonSeries.data = [{
  "id": "US",
  "color": am4core.color("#3F4B3B"),
  "description": "The U.S. is a country of 50 states covering a vast swath of North America, with Alaska in the northwest and Hawaii extending the nation’s presence into the Pacific Ocean. Major Atlantic Coast cities are New York, a global finance and culture center, and capital Washington, DC. Midwestern metropolis Chicago is known for influential architecture and on the west coast, Los Angeles' Hollywood is famed for filmmaking."
}, {
  "id": "CA",
  "color": am4core.color("#3F4B3B"),
  "description": "Canada is a North American country stretching from the U.S. in the south to the Arctic Circle in the north. Major cities include massive Toronto, west coast film centre Vancouver, French-speaking Montréal and Québec City, and capital city Ottawa. Canada's vast swaths of wilderness include lake-filled Banff National Park in the Rocky Mountains. It's also home to Niagara Falls, a famous group of massive waterfalls."
}, {
  "id": "MX",
  "color": am4core.color("#3F4B3B"),
  "description": "Mexico is a country between the U.S. and Central America that's known for its Pacific and Gulf of Mexico beaches and its diverse landscape of mountains, deserts and jungles. Ancient ruins such as Teotihuacán and the Mayan city of Chichén Itzá are scattered throughout the country, as are Spanish colonial-era towns. In capital Mexico City, upscale shops, renowned museums and gourmet restaurants cater to modern life."
}]

// Configure series
var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";
polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#5CAB7D");
polygonTemplate.propertyFields.fill = "color";
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  var data = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext;
  var info = document.getElementById("info");
  info.innerHTML = "<h3>" + data.name + " (" + data.id  + ")</h3>";
  if (data.description) {
    info.innerHTML += data.description;
  }
  else {
    info.innerHTML += "<i>No description provided.</i>"
  }
});

// Add image series
var imageSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());
imageSeries.mapImages.template.propertyFields.longitude = "longitude";
imageSeries.mapImages.template.propertyFields.latitude = "latitude";
imageSeries.data = [ {
  "title": "Brussels",
  "latitude": 50.8371,
  "longitude": 4.3676
}, {
  "title": "Copenhagen",
  "latitude": 55.6763,
  "longitude": 12.5681
}, {
  "title": "Paris",
  "latitude": 48.8567,
  "longitude": 2.3510
}, {
  "title": "Reykjavik",
  "latitude": 64.1353,
  "longitude": -21.8952
}, {
  "title": "Moscow",
  "latitude": 55.7558,
  "longitude": 37.6176
}, {
  "title": "Madrid",
  "latitude": 40.4167,
  "longitude": -3.7033
}, {
  "title": "London",
  "latitude": 51.5002,
  "longitude": -0.1262,
  "url": "http://www.google.co.uk"
}, {
  "title": "Peking",
  "latitude": 39.9056,
  "longitude": 116.3958
}, {
  "title": "New Delhi",
  "latitude": 28.6353,
  "longitude": 77.2250
}, {
  "title": "Tokyo",
  "latitude": 35.6785,
  "longitude": 139.6823,
  "url": ""
}, {
  "title": "Ankara",
  "latitude": 39.9439,
  "longitude": 32.8560
}, {
  "title": "Buenos Aires",
  "latitude": -34.6118,
  "longitude": -58.4173
}, {
  "title": "Brasilia",
  "latitude": -15.7801,
  "longitude": -47.9292
}, {
  "title": "Ottawa",
  "latitude": 45.4235,
  "longitude": -75.6979
}, {
  "title": "Washington",
  "latitude": 38.8921,
  "longitude": -77.0241
}, {
  "title": "Kinshasa",
  "latitude": -4.3369,
  "longitude": 15.3271
}, {
  "title": "Cairo",
  "latitude": 30.0571,
  "longitude": 31.2272
}, {
  "title": "Pretoria",
  "latitude": -25.7463,
  "longitude": 28.1876
} ];

// add events to recalculate map position when the map is moved or zoomed
chart.events.on( "ready", updateCustomMarkers );
chart.events.on( "mappositionchanged", updateCustomMarkers );



// this function will take current images on the map and create HTML elements for them
function updateCustomMarkers( event ) {
  
  // go through all of the images
  imageSeries.mapImages.each(function(image) {
    // check if it has corresponding HTML element
    if (!image.dummyData || !image.dummyData.externalElement) {
      // create onex
      image.dummyData = {
        externalElement: createCustomMarker(image)
      };
    }

    // reposition the element accoridng to coordinates
    var xy = chart.geoPointToSVG( { longitude: image.longitude, latitude: image.latitude } );
    image.dummyData.externalElement.style.top = xy.y + 'px';
    image.dummyData.externalElement.style.left = xy.x + 'px';
  });

}

// this function creates and returns a new marker element
function createCustomMarker( image ) {
  
  var chart = image.dataItem.component.chart;

  // create holder
  var holder = document.createElement( 'div' );
  holder.className = 'map-marker';
  holder.title = image.dataItem.dataContext.title;
  holder.style.position = 'absolute';

  // maybe add a link to it?
  if ( undefined != image.url ) {
    holder.onclick = function() {
      window.location.href = image.url;
    };
    holder.className += ' map-clickable';
  }

  // create dot
  var dot = document.createElement( 'div' );
  dot.className = 'dot';
  holder.appendChild( dot );

  // create pulse
  var pulse = document.createElement( 'div' );
  pulse.className = 'pulse';
  holder.appendChild( pulse );

  // append the marker to the map container
  chart.svgContainer.htmlElement.appendChild( holder );

  return holder;
}

}); // end am4core.ready()
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="info"></div>

<div id="links">
<a href="/">home</a>
<a href="/ask">message</a>
<a href="/faq">faq</a>
<a href="/characters">characters</a>
<!--Don't delete this. If you do, I'm gonna directly report you for code stealing and your blog will get deleted. If you don't want a credit link and you can, build your own code. -->
<a href="http://castiiel.tumblr.com">credit</a>
</div></div>


 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Check this out: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/popups-and-modals/

Comment: I have read through it but I don't understand much, it seems really complicated. How to connect the city markers that I have in my code to a pop up? I can only literally copy and paste the tutorial part from the link onto my code but that way it only responds to the country and always gives the same text. How can I make the popup to display the info I want and link it to the markers? (I don't even know how to make them clickable in the first place.)